# Obtain patterns from a file, compare to a column of another file, print matching lines, using awk

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep

I'd essentially like to combine the power of

```
grep -f
```

with

```
awk '{ if($2=="this is where I'd like to input a file of fixed string patterns") print $0}'
```

Which is to say, I'd like to search a specific column of a file (File 1) with an input file of patterns (File 2). If a match is found simply:

```
> outputfile.txt
```

From a previous post, this awk line is really close:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next} {n=0;for(i in a){if($0~i){n=1}}} n' file1 file2
```

*Taken from [Obtain patterns in one file from another using ack or awk or better way than grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936962/obtain-patterns-in-one-file-from-another-using-ack-or-awk-or-better-way-than-gre)*

But it doesn't search a specific column of file 1. I'm open to other tools as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you found is indeed very close to what you want, the only difference is that you don't want to match the whole line (`$0`).

Modify it to something like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { pats[$0]=1; next } { for(p in pats) if($2 ~ p) { print $0; break } }' patterns file
```

If you only need a fixed string match, use the `index()` function instead, i.e. replace `$2 ~ p` with `index($2, p)`.

You could also provide the column number as an argument to awk, e.g.:

```
awk -v col=$col 'NR==FNR { pats[$0]=1; next } { for(p in pats) if($col ~ p) { print $0; break } }' patterns file
```

#### Edit - whole field matching

You can accomplish this with the `==` operator:

```
awk -v col=$col 'NR==FNR { pats[$0]=1; next } { for(p in pats) if($col == p) { print $0; break } }' patterns file
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well on smaller numbers of patterns. My patterns are fixed strings, and I only want exact matches. I know that for instance when using Grep, adding a fixed string option really cuts down on processing time. Is there an awk equivalent?

Comment: @ChrisJ.Vargo: yes, the `index` function does fixed string matching (as mentioned in the answer).

Comment: Thanks, but: 

    awk 'NR==FNR { pats[$0]=1; next } { for(p in pats) if(index($5, p)) { print $0; break } }' 1.txt PrimaryTweets.tsv > 1Method2index.tsv

Doesn't return exact matches. Is there a way to force an exact match?

Comment: @ChrisJ.Vargo: so what you really want is whole word matching or is it whole field matching? See the edit for whole field matching. If you mean whole word, you either need to use regex or do some further field splitting.

Answer (score 3):

This is using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { while(getline l < "patterns.txt") PATS[l] } $2 in PATS' file2
```

Where `file1` is the file you are searching, and `patterns.txt` is a file with one exact pattern per file.  The implicit `{print}` has been omitted but you can add it and do anything you like there.

The condition `$2 in PATS` will be true is the second column is exactly one of the patterns.

If `patterns.txt` are to be treated as regexp matches, modify it to

```
ok=0;{for (p in PATS) if ($2 ~ p) ok=1}; ok
```

So, for example, to test `$2` against all the regexps in `patterns.txt`, and print the 
**third** column if the 2nd column matched:

```
awk 'BEGIN { while(getline l < "patterns.txt") PATS[l] } 
     ok=0;{for (p in PATS) if ($2 ~ p) ok=1}; ok 
    {print $3}' < file2
```

And here's a version in `perl`. Similar to the `awk` version except that it
uses regexps instead of fields.

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{open $pf, "<patterns.txt"; %P=map{chomp;$_=>1}<$pf>} 
   /^\s*([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+).*$/ and exists $P{$2} and print' < file2
```

Taking that apart:

```perl
BEGIN{
  open $pf, "<patterns.txt"; 
  %P = map {chomp;$_=>1} <$pf>;
}
```

Reads in your patterns file into a has `%P` for fast lookup.

```
/^\s*([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+).*$/ and  # extract your fields into $1, $2, etc
exists $P{$2} and                 # See if your field is in the patterns hash
print;                            # just print the line (you could also 
                                  # print anything else; print "$1\n"; etc)
```

It gets slightly shorter if your input file is tab-separated (and when you *know* that
there's exactly one tab between fields). Here's an example that matches the patterns
against the *5th* column:

```
 perl -F"\t" -ane '
    BEGIN{open $pf, "<patterns.txt"; %P=map{chomp;$_=>1}<$pf>} 
    exists $P{$F[4]} and print ' file2
```

This is thanks to perl's `-F` operator that tells perl to auto-split into columns
based on the separator (`\t` in this case).
Note that since arrays in `perl` start from `0`, `$F[4]` is the 5th field.

Comment: Impressive. Seems like I cannot longer avoid dealing with `awk`. Thank you for the detailed explanations.

Comment: Thanks! This works well on smaller numbers of patterns. On my large list of 1,000, it seems to run out of memory. My patterns are fixed strings, and I only want exact matches. I know that for instance when using Grep, adding a fixed string option (-F) really cuts down on processing time. Is there an awk equivalent?

Comment: What if you try the `perl` version I just posted?

Comment: What version of `awk` and what kind of `OS` are you running on?

Comment: When fed a large list, the perl version only seems to retrieve one pattern, and then exits. Running Mountain Lion.

Comment: You mean the last `perl` example?  Also,  I noticed that you refer to your input file as `file2`..  Curious to know What's the output of `xxd file1 | head`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure which part the distinction of columns plays in this scenario. Do you process some kind of csv file? Do you take care of column delimiters in the regex list file? If there are no distinct columns separated by certain delimiters in your file, you could just use `grep`:

```
grep -o -f file2 file1
```

If columns is an issue, maybe something like this:

```
grep -o "[^,]*" file1 | grep -f file2
```

where `,` is the delimiter.

Comment: It's tab separated, fifth column. Can grep just skip the first 55 characters, and then only return a match if it's found before the first tab? This would force it to start in the 5th column, and stop before the next one. I like grep, because with the fixed strings option, it is much quicker than awk.

Comment: There is a bug in `grep` regarding tabs, but by using the Perl switch `-P`, you can pass them like you would expect: `\t`. However, it seems more suitable to use `cut` here, whose delimiter is tab by default and that could prepare your file1 (`-f 5`).