# grep -f file to print in order as a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a a requirement to grep patterns from a file but need them in order.

```
$ cat patt.grep
name1
name2

$ grep -f patt.grep myfile.log
name2:some xxxxxxxxxx
name1:some xxxxxxxxxx
```

I am getting the output as name2 was found first it was printed then name1 is found it is also printed. But my requirement is to get the name1 first as per the order of patt.grep file.

I am expecting the output as

```
name1:some xxxxxxxxxx
name2:some xxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: @devnull probably the patterns in patt.grep are unsorted, and the OP wants them sorted in the order in patt.grep. Unfortunately the example is likely misleading.

Comment: @mockinterface but it seems to be sorted like see the output of `$ cat patt.grep`

Comment: @JKB I bet that it is unsorted. Call it a hunch developed after years and years of reading the minds of requirement writers. Will go to sleep and find out in the morning :)

Comment: @Sriharsha Kalluru Try `$ grep -f patt.grep myfile.log | sort -u`

Comment: sort -u will apply for my script but my requirement is get order as per the list of patt.grep file.

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936962/obtain-patterns-in-one-file-from-another-using-ack-or-awk-or-better-way-than-gre

Comment: The output of this command is *in the order the lines appear in `myfile.log`*, not the order of the patterns in `patt.grep`. `name2` occurs in `myfile.log` before `name1` does. `grep` walks through the file-to-be-searched one line at a time and compares each line to all patterns. If you want it in pattern order, then you'll have to run `grep` repeatedly, once for each pattern.

Answer (score 5):

You can pipe `patt.grep` to `xargs`, which will pass the patterns to `grep` one at a time.

By default `xargs` appends arguments at the end of the command. But in this case, `grep` needs `myfile.log` to be the last argument.  So use the `-I{}` option to tell `xargs` to replace `{}` with the arguments.

```
cat patt.grep | xargs -Ihello grep hello myfile.log
```

Comment: If invoking `grep` for every line in `patt.grep` is tolerable in terms of performance, this is a simple and pragmatic solution. (I suggest using `{}` or something similarly abstract as the placeholder, though, to avoid confusion.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the regexes in `patt.grep` one after another in order of appearance by reading line-wise:

```
while read ptn; do grep $ptn myfile.log; done < patt.grep
```

Comment: While loop creates n number of process if there are n number of patterns and I am not preferring that one. I am looking for a generic option if there is any available with grep directly.

Comment: Maybe apply line wise matching to the output of `grep -f patt.grep myfile.log`, then?

Comment: I am not aware of line wise matching can you please provide the command.

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround would be to `sort` the log file before `grep`:

```
grep -f patt.grep <(sort -t: myfile.log)
```

However, this might not yield results in the desired order if `patt.grep` is not sorted.

In order to preserve the order specified in the pattern file, you might use `awk` instead:

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}$1 in a' patt.grep myfile.log
```

Comment: But i think OP wants order as per the list of `patt.grep` file.

Comment: @JKB Yes, the `awk` solution does preserve the order as in the pattern file.

Comment: Actually, the `awk` solution preserves the order as in the _log_ (input) file, not the pattern file; it is effectively the same as the OP's original command, `grep -f patt.grep myfile.log`.

Answer (score 1):

i tried the same situation and easily solved using below command:

I think if your data in the same format as you represent then you can use this.

```
grep -f patt.grep myfile.log | sort
```

[image]

Comment: But i think OP wants order as per the list of patt.grep file.

Comment: I mentioned name1 and name2 just for testing but my actual requirement may be with different words.

Comment: Then you can use "while read line; do grep $line myfile.log; done < patt.grep" which i thnik answer is already given below by J. Katzwinkel

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

awk -F":" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}{ if ($1 in a) {print a[$0]} else {print $1, $1} }' myfile.log patt.grep > z

Comment: While this snippet may answer the question, we typically prefer some additional explanation as to how or why something is so.  Can you provide an explanation?

Comment: Hi, sorry, so: first, the myfile.log is split into columns using -F":". Then I load the content into a with a[$1]=$0. Then I say if a word listed in the first (and only) column of patt.grep is present in the first column of a (which is essentially created by splitting in with -F":" and contains name2, name1 in this order), then I say print the entire line, otherwise print the missing word twice. So if you add name3 into patt.grep, the output is: 
name1:some xxxxxxxxxx
name2:some xxxxxxxxxx
name3 name3

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done in `grep` alone.

For a simple and pragmatic, but inefficient solution, see [owlman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29480466/45375). It invokes `grep` *once for each pattern* in `patt.grep`.

If that's not an option, consider the following approach:

```
grep -f patt.grep myfile.log |
 awk -F: 'NR==FNR { l[$1]=$0; next } $1 in l {print l[$1]}' - patt.grep
```

- Passes all patterns to `grep` in a single pass,
- then sorts them based on the order of patterns in `patt.grep` using `awk`:

  - first reads all output lines (passed via stdin, `-`, i.e., through the pipe) into an assoc. array using the 1st `:`-based field as the key
  - then loops over the lines of `patt.grep` and prints the corresponding output line, if any.

*Constraints*:

- Assumes that all patterns in `patt.grep` match the 1st `:`-based token in the log file, as implied by the sample output data in the question.
- Assumes that each pattern only matches *once* - if multiple matches are possible, the `awk` solution would have to be made more sophisticated.